# Queston about define a function in a class

Tags: python, methods

`if len(self.students) < self.max_students`

Not sure what the above codes are used for on the following statement, if anyone can help?

```
class course:
    def __init__(self,name,max_students):
        self.name = name
        self.max_students = max_students
        self.students = [] #empty list
        
    def add_student(self,student):
        if len(self.students) < self.max_students:
            self.students.append(student)
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: Hi, is is this self.<something> unclear to you or what?

Comment: if the the number of items in list of students is still less than the max, then append and return true otherwise don't append and return false

Answer (score 1):

This statement check before adding a student to the list that the number of the students in the course is smaller than the maximum students can join the course( `max_students` ). if the number of the students is smaller than the maximum the code add the variable `student` to the list.

`self` is used to access in the class atributes(variables, functions, etc...)

`len` is used to check the length of an object

The class defined in the code have three variables:

- `max_students` - a number that save the maximum number of students that can join the course
- `students` - list that saves the students that are in the course
- `name` - a string that contain the course name

Answer (score 0):

```
if len(self.students) < self.max_students
```

Here `self.max_students` defines the capacity of the student's list or it's just like a maximum number of students should be allowed inside a class.

So, here we are checking whether the number of students in a class should not exceed the capacity.

Answer (score 0):

It was to control that the max_student value for the instance of this class is not exceeded. That permits to avoid to add indefinitely values

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add your comments by using "Add comment", instead of posting as answer.